# Unable to connect to Cloud SQL from app engine (python)

Tags: python, mysql, google-app-engine

I'm getting the following when trying to connect to Cloud SQL from app engine using python:

super(Connection, self).**init**(*args, **kwargs2)
OperationalError: (2013, "Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 38")

Here's my connect code:

```
CLOUDSQL_PROJECT = 'some-project'
CLOUDSQL_REGION = 'us-central1'
CLOUDSQL_INSTANCE = 'some-instance'

class connect():
    def __init__(self,dbname):
        # When running on Google App Engine, use the special unix socket
        # to connect to Cloud SQL.
        if os.getenv('SERVER_SOFTWARE', '').startswith('Google App Engine/'):
            self.db = MySQLdb.connect(
                unix_socket='/cloudsql/{}:{}:{}'.format(
                    CLOUDSQL_PROJECT,
                    CLOUDSQL_REGION,
                    CLOUDSQL_INSTANCE),
                db=dbname,
                user='root@localhost',
                passwd='********')
        # When running locally, you can either connect to a local running
        # MySQL instance, or connect to your Cloud SQL instance over TCP.
        else:
            self.db = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost', user='root', passwd='**********',db=dbname)
```

My app and mysql instance live in the same region (us-central). I'm using "2nd generation mysql" version so there's no need to whitelist the app.

I've read and reread the docs, googled until I'm blue, and tried numerous variations of the connection string to no avail. I am able to connect from the dev environment.

At this point I think it's a google issue but as a "bronze" support client I have no way to contact them.

Thanks.

Comment: Try with just `user='root'`. Have you followed all the steps [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/app-engine-connect) under the "App Engine standard environment to Second Generation" heading? Is your application in the same project as your Cloud SQL instance?

Comment: Yes, `user='root'`.  Also try: `unix_socket=':/cloudsql/{}:{}:{}'.format(`  (notice extra colon at start of string)

Comment: Tried extra colon. Nope. I get: OperationalError: (2001, "Can't create UNIX socket (-1)")

Comment: I reverted to mysql v1 and things are working. My app is a few years old and I suspect that there's a config setting that google neglected to set. Also having trouble with a blobstore upload that works fine in a virgin account. Will be posting about that shortly. May resort to copying all of my data to a new app engine project. :(